# Realm object server MacOs error

Tags: ios, swift, macos, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am trying to start the realm object server, but when the terminal launch I get the follow message:

```
 Last login: Wed Sep 28 12:09:13 on ttys003 
/Users/idanaviv10/Downloads/realm-mobile-platform/realm-object-server/realm-generate-admin-token ; exit;
Idans-iMac:~ idanaviv10$ /Users/idanaviv10/Downloads/realm-mobile-platform/realm-object-server/realm-generate-admin-token ; exit;
2016-09-28T12:11:16+0300 [ERROR] Could not find private key at `/etc/realm/token-signature.key'.
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Somebody knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may not be running the correct command. The `realm-generate-admin-token` command is used to generate an authentication token, not start the server.

Normally, on macOS, you should run the `start-object-server.command` script.

Comment: Thank you so much!